# How do I exit form "Failed validating schema (@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:package)" in Jupyter lab?

Tags: ssh, jupyter, exit, hung

I am trying to access jupyter lab using ssh. I am fallen in this error message shown in the image that I attach:

[image]

It is a similar problem reported in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260338/what-is-a-failed-validating-schema-jupyterlab-apputils-extensionpackage-in) StackOverflow post.

My problem now is: how do I exit from this and obtain my command line again ? As you can see I have tried `q` `exit()` `quit()` `q` `exit` ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Ctrl+D. Is perhaps the cause of the error a bad PATH variable? Which are the operating systems on both sides?

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your comment. I tried Ctrl+D but it stays still there. My computer is Windows 10 and on the other side, to be honest, I do not know... either Linux or Windows.

Comment: The best solution might be to fix the error, which might be because of a mixup of versions. Otherwise, if the program is hung, killing it might be the answer.

Comment: How can I kill it in this situation ? @harrymc

Comment: Try Ctrl-C, but your options are limited if you don't control the server. Get in touch perhaps with the server's administrator for solving the error itself.

Comment: @harrymc Ctrl-C has worked thanks! If you post it as an answer I can give you the 50 bounty points.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the hung process.

This is a strong-arm solution that aborts the interactive program,
but it's effective in most cases.